# Reset default value on radio button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having an issue with some jQuery that I am using in an asp.net mvc3 application that handles mutually exclusive radio buttons.  The check/unchecking part works fine but the value of the radio button control is left with it's true value even though it is unchecked.

Here is the jQuery that I'm using:

```
$('.customRadio').click(function () {
    var checkState = $(this).attr('checked');
    $('.customRadio:checked').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
    $(this).attr('checked', checkState);
});
```

I've tried setting the `.val('myValue')` property with jQuery like so but it's not working:

```
$(this).val($(this).getAttribute("falsevalue"));
```

Here is the rendered html:

```
<div class="one columns " style="min-width: 64px;">

                    <label for="Approve" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Approve</label>
                    <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                    <label for="Approve" class="show-on-phones">Approve &nbsp; </label>
                    <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        

                <input class="customRadio" falsevalue="N" id="Approve" name="Approve" truevalue="Y" type="radio" value="N">
            </div>

<div class="one columns " style="min-width: 50px;">

                    <label for="Reject" class="hide-on-phones" style="white-space: nowrap">Reject</label>
                    <span class="clearfix hide-on-phones"></span>
                    <label for="Reject" class="show-on-phones">Reject &nbsp; </label>
                    <span class="clearfix show-on-phones"></span>                        

                <input class="customRadio" falsevalue="Y" id="Reject" name="Reject" truevalue="N" type="radio" value="Y">
            </div>
```

I am inspecting the elements with Chrome.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getAttribute is a native JS method, use attr() :

```
$(this).val($(this).attr("falsevalue"));
```

Be aware that if you're inspecting the element in a DOM inspector, like chrome or firebug, the checked property will not change even if you programmatically change it, but it will be changed when the form submits. And there should'nt be a need for a loop, simply doing `$('.customRadio:checked').prop('checked', false);` should do (and being a property, prop() would be the correct method).

Comment: attr() is being deprecated, use prop()

Comment: @HighParkCoder - I will if you show me the documentation where it says prop() should now be used for attributes as well.

Comment: @adeneo +1, and plus one for that comment. Though you could just use `this.getAttribute("falsevalue")`

Comment: I stand corrected, but .prop is a better way to check if a checkbox is checked or not, and that **is** in the documentation, your lordship

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know there is no `falsevalue` property, it's probably an attribute ?

Comment: @JosephSilber - You're right, I just went with the jQuery version, but either one will work.

Comment: Thank you to everyone.  adeneo, don't I have to loop it since there are 2 radio buttons on the page?  The way this system was initially architected, it is different than a typical MVC application.  There is a custom built framework that it sits on and we have to code around that.  I will edit my initial question to add the rendered html.

Comment: The selector selects all elements that match, and changing the property changes it for all the elements selected by that selector, so no, you should'nt have to loop the elements, as prop() probably does that internally anyway.